# Mysql datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP error

Tags: mysql, linux, windows

**1.**
When I ran this MYSQL syntax on windows it ran properly:

```
CREATE TABLE New
(
  id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timeUp datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

But when I tried running this code on Linux I got an error:

```
 #1067 - Invalid default value for 'time'
```

**2.**
On windows the case is not sensitive eg. `New` and `new` both are considered to be same. But on linux the case is sensitive.

Configuration of Linux:

MySQL 5.5.33, phpMyAdmin: 4.0.5, PHP: 5.2.17

Configuration of Windows:

MySql: 5.6.11, phpMyAdmin: 4.0.4.1, PHP: 5.5.0

Is there any way to make them common for both systems? Or any alternative approach?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The **`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** support for a **`DATETIME`** (datatype) was added in MySQL 5.6.

In 5.5 and earlier versions, this applied only to **`TIMESTAMP`** (datatype) columns.

It is possible to use a **`BEFORE INSERT`** trigger in 5.5 to assign a default value to a column.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER ...
 BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.mycol IS NULL THEN
       SET NEW.mycol = NOW();
    END IF;
 END$$
```

---

<strike>Case sensitivity (of queries against values stored in columns) is due to the **`collation`** used for the column. Collations ending in **`_ci`** are case insensitive. For example **`latin1_swedish_ci`** is case insensitive, but **`latin1_general_cs`** is case sensitive.</strike>

The output from **`SHOW CREATE TABLE foo`** will show the character set and collation for the character type columns.  This is specified at a per-column level. The "default" specified at the table level applies to new columns added to the table when the new column definition doesn't specify a characterset.

**UPDATE**

Kaii pointed out that my answer regarding "case sensitivity" deals with values stored within columns, and whether queries will return a value from a column containing a value of `"New"` will be returned with a predicate like  `"t.col = 'new'"`.

See Kaii's answer regarding **identifiers** (e.g. table names) being handled differently (by default) on Windows than on Linux.

Comment: can you tell me how I can perform Collations ending

Comment: I think the OP asked about the case sensitivity of *identifiers* (table names, schema names) and not *values* in the columns. In fact, the COLLATION is applied on both platforms *equally*, so you wouldn't run into problems with CS/CI collations when cloning databases using different operating systems. However, this doesn't apply for identifiers, as those directly correspond to the filesystem used to store the datafiles. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Kaii: good point. I was speaking specifically of "case sensitivity" in terms of character type columns and expressions used in queries.  OP said `'New'` and `'new'` "were considered to be the same". I took that to be the value within a column, not an identifier since `'NEW'` is a reserved word we wouldn't use as an identifier.

Comment: FWIW: the OP creates a table named `New` and that's the only occurance of this string in his example.

Comment: @Kaii: yes, I entirely missed that. Excerpt from the MySQL documentation **9.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity**:  "To avoid problems caused by such differences, it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as **always** creating and referring to databases and tables using **lowercase names**. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use." And that's the convention we **always** follow, and we never encounter problems with case sensitivity. It always throws me for a loop when I see identifiers containing an uppercase character.

Comment: @spencer7593 good quote. i incorporated that into my answer for completeness

Answer (score 4):

As the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` question is already answered, i will only respond to the case-sensitivity mismatch in table names between windows and linux.

On Windows, file systems are by default case-insensitive.
But on Linux and other *NIX like Operating Systems, they are case-sensitive by default.

The reason why you get a mismatch in behaviour here is the file system, as each table is created as a separate file and the filesystem handles case-sensitivity for you.

MySQL has a parameter to override this behaviour:

> For example, on Unix, you can have two different tables named `my_table`
>   and `MY_TABLE`, but on Windows these two names are considered identical.
>   To avoid data transfer problems arising from lettercase of database or
>   table names, you have two options:
>
> - Use `lower_case_table_names=1` on all systems. The main disadvantage with this is that when you use `SHOW TABLES` or `SHOW DATABASES`, you do
>     not see the names in their original lettercase.
> - Use `lower_case_table_names=0` on Unix and `lower_case_table_names=2` on Windows. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names.
>     The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements
>     always refer to your database and table names with the correct
>     lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where
>     lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is
>     incorrect.
>   ***Exception:*** If you are using InnoDB tables and you are trying to avoid these data transfer problems, you should set `lower_case_table_names=1` on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase.
>
> [...]
>   To avoid problems caused by such differences,
>   **it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating
>   and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names**. This
>   convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.

This is an excerpt from the [MySQL manual on the case sensitivity of identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: @JohnyPie this is a configuration option. you need to put it into your `my.cnf` and restart mysql to change this behaviour.

Comment: @JohnyPie but the manual clearly states: it's best to adopt a consistent convention (like writing all table names in lower case) instead of messing around with the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

if you wants to default time to must change to `timestamp` in your datatype,

the `datetime` is going to display the user input of table...

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html**

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html**

Comment: spencer7593 already answered my 1st question, can you answer my 2nd question