# MySQL invalid default value for [something]

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

I tried to restore external MySQL DB in my window MySQL.

```
mysql -u root -p test < C:\Users\myname\Downloads\db.sql
```

but there is error like this.

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 200: Invalid default value for 'VERSION_DATE'
```

some people said that it was caused by character encoding so i tried this again.

```
mysql -u root -p test < C:\Users\myname\Downloads\db.sql --default-character-set=utf8
```

but same error.

what is wrong with this MySQL restoring.

here's the line 200 starts.

```
CREATE TABLE `APP_EVENT_HISTORY` (
  `OWNER_ID` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `APP_ID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `EVENT_ID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `VERSION_ID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `VERSION_DATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `SCRIPT` text,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_USER_ID` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UPDATE_USER_ID` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OWNER_ID`,`APP_ID`,`EVENT_ID`,`VERSION_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: as a first step, check table definition on that row in your SQL file. will be very helpful to paste that piece of code here.

Comment: if you cannot access SQL file, how do you expect to fix the error?

Comment: VERSION_DATE - `datetime` format cannot access default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so either change it to `timestamp` type or make it `DEFAULT NULL` or `NOT NULL`, depending of your needs.

Comment: Does this error came from MySQL version difference? I installed MySQL 5.5 version.

Comment: yes, this is possible since version 5.6.5, so if you want to keep this, you need to upgrade your MySQL version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link which may prove useful:
[Mysql datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153822/mysql-datetime-default-current-timestamp-error)

Yes, it may be due to difference on mysql versions (if you did the backup on one version and restoring on another one).

Comment: Hi, it would be very helpful if you could copy the pertinent information from the link in case it goes stale, would make your answer even better :)