# Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Tags: mysql, database

i am getting error in my database. i am encountering invalid default value for timestamp.

here's my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `threadId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `isModified` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=171 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `color` varchar(10) DEFAULT '#00bcd4',
  `icon` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'https://mymonas.com/forum/category_icon/ic_question.png'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can I suggest you change your character set to `UTF8mb4`, as this will sidestep issues with wyrd characters in the future. [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: same problem i got ,#1067 - Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Comment: Oh yeah, it's  an aside, not a solution in itself.

Comment: Use `TIMESTAMP` data type or update your MySQL server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql datetime DEFAULT CURRENT\_TIMESTAMP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153822/mysql-datetime-default-current-timestamp-error)

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem, I changed type from "datetime" to "timestamp" and It worked. I have mysql 5.5.52.

[Mysql_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnkoB.png)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue in sql_mode.

Make query:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

You need to remove  the  "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE" from sql_mode.

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() instead CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `threadId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `isModified` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=171 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now() works as well

Comment: same error again. error not fix i just put () but it wont work

Comment: Which version of mySQL do you use

Comment: Phpmyadmin Version information: 4.0.10.7, latest stable version: 4.6.0 and   Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

Comment: Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.48-cll

Comment: try to use  NOW() instead it

Comment: i found what is wrong 
timestamp was be added in MySQL only in 5.6.4 version.
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP since 5.6.5
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: o i see. then instead of timestamp what should i use?

Comment: Just datetime. And MySQL did not have a way to use default value before 5.6.5. You should add date in insert statement

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL 5.5 manual:

> "You cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column."

The changes in MYSQL 5.6.x that allow the functionality are documented here:

> "As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table."

So, this means you are using an older version of mysql, either you can use datetime data type of upgrade your mysql version

Answer (score 1):

Answered by  [@max Sherbakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52929582/5803974) worked but I think its risky,

if you execute `SET sql_mode = '';` query.

Because if you or other users **SET** any different variables in **sql_mode**

like ***NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION*** [check other SQL MODES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

by changing **sql_mode** values in  **my.ini** file

OR

using `SET sql_mode = 'YOUR_VARIABLE_LIST';` query

it worked for you current situation

but create problem in other projects.

- To view current sql mode use following query

  `show variables like 'sql_mode' ;`