# sql import error, invalid default value

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have google the problem I guess I am not the expert in sql thats why I cant seem to solve it.

I am exporting database from dedicated server and trying to import into google cloud instance apache / sql 
I get error like below even I tried all answers in stackoverflow

```
Error
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE `islemler` (
  `islemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `islemKullaniciID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `islemTarih` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `islemBitisTarihi` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `islemDurum` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `islemNot` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci
MySQL said: Documentation
```

## 1067 - Invalid default value for 'islemTarih'

please see the screen shot from link
[Old database](http://prntscr.com/gyzar2)

[New Database error](http://prntscr.com/gyzcb6)

I appreciate some help...

---

As additional

I manage to create all tables manual, as much as from my sql knowledge.
I run below commands
CREATE TABLE `oradamis_vt`.`islemler` ( `islemID` INT(11) NOT NULL , `islemKullaniciID` INT(11) NOT NULL , `islemTarih` DATETIME NOT NULL , `islemBitisTarihi` DATETIME NOT NULL , `islemDurum` VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `islemNot` VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_turkish_ci NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `oradamis_vt`.`kullanicilar` ( `kullaniciID` INT(11) NOT NULL , `username` VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `kullaniciAdi` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `kullaniciPozisyon` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `kullaniciSkype` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `kullaniciMail` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `kullaniciTelefon` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `kullaniciYetki` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `oradamis_vt`.`version` ( `versionNumber` INT(11) NOT NULL , `sonIslemKullanici` VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL , `sonIslem` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

But at the end when I try to import from old SQL gives same error of startup.

quite frustrated :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid default value for 'timestamp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747096/invalid-default-value-for-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with:

```
CREATE TABLE islemler ( islemID int(11) NOT NULL, islemKullaniciID int(11) NOT NULL, islemTarih timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, islemBitisTarihi datetime DEFAULT NULL, islemDurum varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL, islemNot varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci MySQL said: Documentation
```

Comment: I run in sql command 
error came up as below.

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MySQL said: Documentation' at line 1

Comment: I tried to find CREATE TABLE islemler
in SQL Export file but couldnt find anything relevant.
please see the screen shot.
http://prntscr.com/gz06dn

Comment: After digging more and editing export file from old sql export.
I got more errors now :o

screen shot
http://prntscr.com/gz09uu

Comment: So, try replacing CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). Let me know

Comment: still same errror.
http://prntscr.com/gz4z22

check this screen shot please.
if I did coding right 
http://prntscr.com/gz4zha