# unable to upload sql files in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am Trying To Upload a Database File Include 20 Tables But Only 3 Tables Are Getting Uploaded What To Do

First Day New Job Please Help
[image]

Comment: You might start by reading the error message. It's telling exactly what the problem is that is stopping the execution of the file. The file "uploaded" just fine, the problem is in the execution of the code in the file. After that, you might want to read the help section on Stack Overflow to learn how to ask a question that will get useful answers, and the types of questions that are appropriate on SO.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thanx For Responding, Let Me Add Last Time I Uploaded The Same Files All Went Good | What to Do

Comment: I doubt one of: 1) they are the same files, 2) If they are, all didn't go well. __Read the error message__.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql datetime DEFAULT CURRENT\_TIMESTAMP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153822/mysql-datetime-default-current-timestamp-error)

Comment: @Aj334 ThankYou It Works